# Android Google Play Hangs

Tags: applications, google-play-store

```
When ever i download an app from google play my entire UI is stuck until i press back    
button. Is it a device problem ?
```

I don't see this in some other devices but seen in some also.

Persistent issue is in `Micromax A68` and `Nexus 4`. Since its an inbuilt application how can i fix this issue.